# Add to YouTube subtitles in a non-listed language

Tags: youtube, subtitles

I'd like to add subtitles in a [non-listed yet language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berber_languages) on YouTube.

I've already seen something like this on YouTube.

[image]

How to do that?

Comment: I know for sure this used to be possible, as the video [Translate This Blog!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5J5zjQ3HTc) has subtitles for 68 different languages, including "French - Dexter's Laboratory". However, YouTube may have removed the option for custom languages at some point.